# How to add hours,minutes and seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two times in_time and out_time.I want to add these two times using javascript.How can I do this? The value of in_time and out_time are coming from the text box.
My html code is

```
<div>   
<b>PunchIn</b>
    <input type="text" id="intime" class="time" placeholder="09:00:00" />
    <p class="error">PunchTime is not valid</p>
</div>
<br/>
<div>   
    <b>OutTime</b>
    <input type="text" id="brktime" class="time" placeholder="06:00:00" />
    <p class="error1">OutTime is not valid</p>
</div>
```

You can see the code from [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gxDcn/2/#update)

Comment: Do you use 24 hour clock or AM/PM suffix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is javascript, Second calculation also included

Try this,

```
var a = "17.30.15hrs"
var b = "1.30.20hrs"

alert(addtime(a, b));

var a = "23.00.25hrs"
var b = "1.30.60hrs"

alert(addtime(a, b));

function addtime(start_time, end_time) {
    var startArr = start_time.replace('hrs', '', start_time).split('.');
    var endArr = end_time.replace('hrs', '', end_time).split('.');

    var d = new Date();
    startArr[0] = (startArr[0]) ? parseInt(startArr[0], 10) : 0;
    startArr[1] = (startArr[1]) ? parseInt(startArr[1], 10) : 0;
    startArr[2] = (startArr[2]) ? parseInt(startArr[2], 10) : 0;
    endArr[0] = (endArr[0]) ? parseInt(endArr[0], 10) : 0;
    endArr[1] = (endArr[1]) ? parseInt(endArr[1], 10) : 0;
    endArr[2] = (endArr[2]) ? parseInt(endArr[2], 10) : 0;

    d.setHours(startArr[0] + endArr[0]);
    d.setMinutes(startArr[1] + endArr[1]);
    d.setSeconds(startArr[2] + endArr[2]);

    var hours = d.getHours();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var seconds = d.getSeconds();

    return hours + '.' + minutes + '.' + seconds + 'hrs';
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AXVPf/7/

**Updated** with second calculation

Answer (score 10):

Convert the times to seconds, add them, and format the result:

```
function toSeconds(s) {
  var p = s.split(':');
  return parseInt(p[0], 10) * 3600 + parseInt(p[1], 10) * 60 + parseInt(p[2], 10);
}

function fill(s, digits) {
  s = s.toString();
  while (s.length < digits) s = '0' + s;
  return s;
}

var sec = toSeconds(intime) + toSeconds(out);

var result =
  fill(Math.floor(sec / 3600), 2) + ':' +
  fill(Math.floor(sec / 60) % 60, 2) + ':' +
  fill(sec % 60, 2);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/JLh6W/

Comment: @Guffa- pls check this link also http://jsfiddle.net/gxDcn/4/
I need a 12 hour clock calculation

Comment: @Guffa- there I add a new time 08:00:00.By doint this I got the answer like 28:00:00.Its not a time. right?

Comment: @Agent1: If that's not the desired result, what do you want instead?

Comment: @Guffa-I want it like this, first add intime and 08:00:00. after that add this with the out time. But the answer must be in the format of 12 hour clock or 24 hour clock. Hope you understand

Comment: @Agent1: How do you want to determine if the answer should be in 12 hour or 24 hour format?

Comment: @Guffa-in the case of 12 hour its not a problem. I want only one of this

Comment: @Agent1: And what do you want the result to look, and what should happen when there are more than 12 hours in the result?

Comment: @Guffa- 
if the sum is 18:45:00,then the answer will be intime + 08:00:00 + outtime = 06:45:00

Comment: @Agent1: I don't know where that extra 8 hours come from, but I assume that you mean that a result like 18:45:00 should be displayed as 06:45:00 instead. You can use `% 12` on the value for the hours to get it in the 0-11 range and discard the extra hours.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/timrwood/moment The minutes library covers most of the things you need. 
Check out the Google Closure Library date implementation as well. http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/namespace_goog_date.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function below to convert your time strings into numbers, which you can then just add together

```
function getTimeAsSeconds(time){
    var timeArray = time.split(':');
    return Number(timeArray [0]) * 3600 + Number(timeArray [1]) * 60 + Number(timeArray[2]);
}
```

Something like:

```
var timeInSeconds = getTimeAsSeconds(document.getElementById('intime').value) + getTimeAsSeconds(document.getElementById('brktime').value);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many libraries out there (didn't do a google search, but @alex23 has one). However, the process is usually the same. Convert the strings to least common denominator. In this case seconds. Once you have the seconds add the two together then convert it back to hours minutes seconds again. These conversions are simple multiplications and devisions as @codebox demonstrated.